# ui router - nested views with shared controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an abstract parent view that is meant to share a controller with its nested views.

```
.state('edit', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/home/edit/:id',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/editView.html',
    controller: 'editController'
})
.state('edit.details', {
    url: '/details',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/editDetailsView.html'
})
.state('edit.info', {
    url: '/info',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/editInfoView.html'
})
```

The routing works as expected.

The problem is that when I update a `$scope` variable from one of the nested views, the change is not reflected in the view. When I do the same from the parent view, it works fine. This is not situation that requires an `$apply`.

My guess is that a new instance of `editController` is being created for each view, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The issue here would be related to this Q & A: [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310).

The way how to solve it is hidden in the:

#### [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

> In AngularJS, a child scope normally prototypically inherits from its parent scope.
>    ...
>
> Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play.

```
// So, use
<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1"> 
// rather than
<input type="text" ng-model="prop1">.
```

And also this

#### [Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only)

> Keep in mind that scope properties only inherit down the state chain if the views of your states are nested. Inheritance of scope properties has nothing to do with the nesting of your states and everything to do with the nesting of your views (templates).
>
> It is entirely possible that you have nested states whose templates populate ui-views at various non-nested locations within your site. In this scenario you cannot expect to access the scope variables of parent state views within the views of children states.

Having that we should do this in edit Controller

```
controller('editController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.Model = $scope.Model || {SomeProperty : "xxx"};
})
```

And we can even reuse that `controller: 'editController'` *(we can do not have to, because the $scope.Model will be there - thanks to inheritance)*

```
.state('edit', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/home/edit/:id',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/editView.html',
    controller: 'editController'
})
.state('edit.details', {
    url: '/details',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/editDetailsView.html',
    controller: 'editController'
})
.state('edit.info', {
    url: '/info',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/editInfoView.html',
    controller: 'editController'
})
```

Now, the same controller will be instantiated many times (parent all the children) but the `$scope.Model` will be initiated only once (inside of parent) and available everywhere

Check this [similar working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cqx77pb4CDI2TXyESYGN?p=preview)

Comment: How does one go about this issue in a Rails app? I have a nested controller with home, and organizations. When I apply a style to the organizations view on its own everything works fine, but a different style applied to the nested organization view is over ridden by the un-nested view.

Comment: Is it possible to do this when using the controllerAs pattern giving the child state it's own controller?

Comment: @PilotBob - hope this will give you [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30994715/1679310)

Answer (score 14):

Based on a comment by [PilotBob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768033/ui-router-nested-views-with-shared-controller/27768108#comment50005694_27768108)

> Is it possible to do this when using the **`controllerAs`** pattern giving the child state it's own controller?

I decided to append another solution, using `controllerAs` while keeping the [above/original concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27768108/1679310)

There is [**a working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/35j5b1Tfl5RTPtBApHCs?p=preview)

The states would be now having different controllers and parent state will name it "parentCtrl" ***(to be NOT overwritten in a child scope with child controller)***

```
 .state("main", {
      controller:'mainController',
      controllerAs: "parentCtrl",
      ...
  .state("main.1", {
      parent: 'main',
      controller:'child1Controller',
      controllerAs: "ctrl",
      ...
  .state("main.2", {
      parent: 'main',
      controller:'child2Controller',
      controllerAs: "ctrl", 
      ...
```

And these are controllers:

```
.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    this.Model =  {Name : "yyy"};
})
.controller('child1Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Model = $scope.parentCtrl.Model;
})
.controller('child2Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Model = $scope.parentCtrl.Model; 
})
```

Check it in action [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/35j5b1Tfl5RTPtBApHCs?p=preview)

Comment: thanks, that's pretty much what I did, injecting scope into the child controller to access the parent model. I thought it would be simpler like using vm.$parent.model in the view, but that didn't work.

Comment: Great answer!
I do think it's a bit confusing to still have the '$scope` parameter in the controller function, as the idea of using controller-as syntax is to use `this` instead of $scope. Of course as far as I understand you WILL still need to inject $scope when you want use watchers in your controller (e.g. $scope.$watch('propName', function...).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using `resolve`

```
.state('edit', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/home/edit/:id',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/editView.html',
    controller: 'editController',
    resolve: {
        baseData: function() {
            return {};
        }
    }
})
.state('edit.details', {
    url: '/details',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/editDetailsView.html',
    controller: 'editController'
})
.state('edit.info', {
    url: '/info',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/editInfoView.html',
    controller: 'editController'
})


.controller('editController', function (baseData) {
    baseData.foo = baseData.foo || 'bar';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the child controller you can do:

```
angular.extend($scope, $scope.$parent)
```

In case the controller is used with alias e.g. 'vm' you can do:

```
let vm = angular.extend(this, $scope.$parent.vm);
```