# binding data between two views within the same state and controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app that has a step through form in one view and a display values view nested in a parent view in the same state. I'm wondering if it is possible to bind the data to the display view to the display view. I can't get it to bind from the input view to the display view

```
 .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('main.report', {
     url: '/report'
     views:{
      'content@':{
       templateUrl:'/views/report/report.Form.html',
       controller: 'reportCtrl'
        },

       'input@main.report':{
        templateUrl: 'views/report/report.input.html'
        },

      'display@main.report':{
       templateUrl:'views/report/report.display.html'
       }
      }
     })
 });
```

input display controller

```
.controller("reportCtrl', function($scope,$http,$state) {
 $scope.reportType =[{label:"Report1",value:"reportOne"}
                    ,{label:"Report2", value:"report2"}]; 
});
```

input Html

```
<select name="selectReport" ng-model="selectedreportType" 
  ng-options="reportType.label in reportType in reportTypes"></select>
```

display html

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Report Type: {{selectedReportType.label))</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There's no comma `,` after `url: '/report'`.

Comment: I added it. It's still not binding.

Comment: I just saw a missing comma. It was not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how to use data sharing among views is via `Model`. There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YxhJdn4aUxelPxOLX6qW?p=preview). To get more understanding why, please check these:

- [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)
- [ui router - nested views with shared controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27768033/1679310)

The state definition will be unchanged. The controller will introduce the `Model`

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('main.report', {
      url: '/report',
      views: {
        'content@': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.Form.html',
          controller: 'reportCtrl'
        },

        'input@main.report': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.input.html',
        }, 

        'display@main.report': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.display.html'
        }
      }
    });
```

The main difference is in the controller

```
.controller('reportCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.Model = {};
    $scope.Model.reportTypes = [{
      label: "Report1",
      value: "reportOne"
    }, {
      label: "Report2",
      value: "report2"
    }];
    $scope.Model.selectedReportType = null;
  });
```

Now we introduced Model - the reference type, which will be shared among the scopes.

The updated views:

input.html

```
<select name="selectReport" 
  ng-model="Model.selectedReportType"
  ng-options="reportType as reportType.label for reportType in Model.reportTypes"
></select>
```

display.html

```
Report Type:
<pre> {{Model.selectedReportType | json}}</pre>
```

Why that works is explained here - [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

The [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YxhJdn4aUxelPxOLX6qW?p=preview)