# Destroy scope before change path in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I use `UI-Router` routing. When I change path from a state to another and going back to same state, I see that old $scope in state is there *(with it's properties)*.

I want to destroy that $scope before state changes, So when I come back to state for second time, there will be a clean new scope. I tried to access scope in this event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
   function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
     // fromState.$scope.$destroy();
});
```

But there isn't any reference to $scope. Can I access scope before change state in angular `UI-Router`?

Comment: I created a plunker and extended my answser.. hope it will help to get more details of my spots...

Comment: @RadimKöhler Thanks alot man! I'm working on it and reading your links :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say, that what you experience is a bit different than you described, or you thought what is happening. Please, check for example this:

- [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)
- [scope and controller instantiation with ui router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29107012/1679310)

In general, once the state change is done (not rejected), the **old** $scope is for sure **destroyed**. If we navigate then back, new `$scope` is created for us. But this *$scope* is created this way:

The source code of the[viewDirective.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/viewDirective.js#L216)

```
    function updateView(firstTime) {
      var newScope,
          name            = getUiViewName(scope, attrs, $element, $interpolate),
          previousLocals  = name && $state.$current && $state.$current.locals[name];

      if (!firstTime && previousLocals === latestLocals) return; // nothing to do
      // HERE
      newScope = scope.$new();
      ...
```

The construct: **`scope.$new();`** is a key to understanding. This in fact means, that we use prototypical inheritance

- [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14049480/1679310)

And that in a nutshell could be described:

> we are provided with a `$scope` which has cloned all the properties from its parent.

So if parent contains some reference (has '.' in the path) like this

```
// parent scope
$scope.Model = {
  ...
};
```

And any child state will change that like this

```
$scope.Model.name = "User";
```

That value will be stored in **parent** state *$scope* and available again ... for any next *child* of this state.

NOTE: the same [viewDirective.js but elswhere](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/viewDirective.js#L189) could be used to demonstrate the fact - **`$scope is destroyed`** if we leave the state:

```
    function cleanupLastView() {
      if (previousEl) {
        previousEl.remove();
        previousEl = null;
      }

      if (currentScope) {
        currentScope.$destroy();
        currentScope = null;
      }
      ...
```

EXTEND

I created [a working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CLfsWIAk4RQMPyRFdJG0?p=preview), with these two states:

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  $scope.Model = {
    SharedName: "This is shared name",
  }
  $scope.NotSharedName = $scope.NotSharedName 
                      || "This name is cloned, but then lives its own way";
}])
.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}])
```

And these two ways how to change values *(all will follow the logic described above)*:

```
<p>this will be shared among all children and parent
  <input ng-model="Model.SharedName" />
</p>
<p>this will always copied from parent, live then in each child
  <input ng-model="NotSharedName" />
</p>
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CLfsWIAk4RQMPyRFdJG0?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

I was going to make an add-on comment on Radim Köhler's post but since I don't have enough rep points, I'll just add an answer here that the only solution I've used so far to circumvent this is to use the ["controller as"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) approach and avoid adding methods/properties on the controller scope that I don't want conflicting due to prototypal behavior.