# AngularJS using child $state controllers to add properties to objects on a parent's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a parent state:

```
.state('contact', {
  url: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
      controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.object.property = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
  }
})
```

And its child:

```
.state('contact.list', {
  url: '...',
  templateUrl: '...', 
  controller: function ($scope) {
    var parentObj = $scope.$parent.object.property[1];
  })
```

As you can see, the state `'contact.list'` is a *child* of the state `'contact'`, and therefore `'contact.list'` has a child scope. I am using the variable `parentObj` to store a reference to the object in the *parent*, `$scope.object.property`.

Anyways, what I would like to do would be to add items onto the *scope* in the child *scope*, and have them be added to the object in the parent *scope*.

For example, if it were possible, it would be cool to be able to add some properties to the child object:

```
.state('contact.list', {
  url: '...',
  templateUrl: '...', 
  controller: function ($scope) {
    var parentObj = $scope.$parent.object.property[1];
    $scope.parentObj.newProperty = 'im a new property!';
  })
```

And have this added to the parent controller, which would then optimally have a scope that has:

```
$scope.object.property[1].newProperty
```

Unfortunately, as far as I know, it's not possible to refer to `$parent` *scopes* in this way, and I don't want to have to go and declare:

```
.state('contact.list', {
  url: '...',
  templateUrl: '...', 
  controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.$parent.object.property[1].newProperty = 'im a new property!';
    $scope.$parent.object.property[1].secondNewProperty = 'im the second new property!';
    $scope.$parent.object.property[1].thirdNewProperty = 'im the third new property!';
  })
```

for every single item I am trying to send to the *parent*. If there is any way to achieve this, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$scope.$emit`, `$scope.$broadcast` are valid ways as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that this could be achieved really easily. Just create a reference object in parent $scope.. and all will work as expected

```
.state('contact', {
  url: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
      controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.Model = {};
  }
})
```

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CLfsWIAk4RQMPyRFdJG0?p=preview), related to this Q & A:

[Destroy scope before change path in ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30287627/1679310)

The state def:

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  $scope.Model = {
    SharedName: "This is shared name",
  }
  $scope.NotSharedName = $scope.NotSharedName 
                      || "This name is cloned, but then lives its own way";
}])
.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}])
```

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir!