# Angular ui.router. Deep nested routes

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state

Here is an example to check http://embed.plnkr.co/uVMlkk/preview

When we navigate to 'page2' route there is a 'hey, I'm a subroute' note.
But once we navigate anywhere else that note will disappear forever.

The goal is to make some nested states to be shown right away (as a default ones).

I assume there should be some cases using $state.go(), but can't figure it out so far. Any help is highly appreciated.

State definition snippet:

```
  .state('root.page2.tab', {
    url: '/:tabId',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.page2.tab.html',
    controller: 'Page2TabController'
  })

  .state('root.page2.tab.subroute', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.page2.tab.subroute.html'
  })
```

the content of the *'tpl.page2.tab.subroute.html'*:

```
hey, I'm a subroute
```

related controller:

```
  .controller('Page2TabController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.tabId = $state.params.tabId;
    $state.go('root.page2.tab.subroute');
  }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick how to handle scenarios:

> Parent should trigger some action in case that
>
> - it is accessed, or
> - its reached again, when navigating **back** from child in a parent state

In that case, we can use the *"target (`ui-view`) for a child"* as a place where sits the special `view`, with special **`controller`**. This will be

- injected into that position once parent is created and
- re-injected into that position again, once child is left. In that case, it will be re-init.

Enough explanation. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZjoZU?p=preview). There is adjusted state:

```
.state('root.page2', {
    url: '/page2',
    views: {
      'content@root': {
        templateUrl: './tpl.page2.html',
        controller: 'Page2Controller'
      },
      '@root.page2': {
        template: '<div></div>',
        controller: 'RedirectorController'
      }
    }
})
```

So, now we can do some magic inside of our **`'RedirectorController'`**

```
.controller('RedirectorController', ['$scope', '$state', 
   function($scope, $state) {
      $state.go('root.page2.tab', { tabId: $scope.activeTabId });
}])
```

Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZjoZU?p=preview)

Read more about what that new view/controller get from the other *(Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only)* one here

- [Nested states or views for layout with leftbar in ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310)
- [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

Comment: Didn't quite get the reason why that magic works, but it does! Have to read up on this more. Thank you Radim.

Comment: If that helped anyhow ... ;) great. Really ;) Here I tried explain that magic in detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/29115009/1679310 ... maybe that could help that it is a trick... using built-in features... and sadly NO magic ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [fixed version](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjYnoT?p=preview).

I removed the url from the `'root.page2.tab.subroute'`

```
.state('root.page2.tab.subroute', {
    //url: '',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.page2.tab.subroute.html'
})
```

And because the parent has defined paramater `tabId`:

```
.state('root.page2.tab', {
    url: '/:tabId',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.page2.tab.html',
    controller: 'Page2TabController'
})
```

We have to pass that param inside of the redicrection:

```
.controller('Page2TabController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.tabId = $state.params.tabId;
    // instead of this
    // $state.go('root.page2.tab.subroute');
    // we need this
    $state.go('root.page2.tab.subroute', $state.params);
 }])
```

Check the working, fixed version [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjYnoT?p=preview)

ANOTHER approach - using **`redirectTo`** - there is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7AYtxx?p=preview)

One way, inspired by this:

[Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310)

could be to add a very smart but small redirect code snippet:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    });
}])
```

And adjust our state like this:

```
.state('root.page2.tab', {
    url: '/:tabId',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.page2.tab.html',
    controller: 'Page2TabController',
    redirectTo: 'root.page2.tab.subroute',
})
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7AYtxx?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, Radim, for you time. We are almost there, but not quite yet. In your example there is a case when I navigate to 'page2', then 'tabId1/2/3' then 'page2' again. - 'root.page2.tab' and 'root.page2.tab.subroute' are not activated any more. Though it works fine once we route 'page1' and 'page2' again. (Same case for both approaches). Any thoughts?

Comment: The point is: going from tabs 1 / 2 / 3 back to page2... does not re-run the 'Page2Controller'. This is their parent, so when going back from child ... parent is still there... not re-init. That's in fact good. Do you really need navigate to some child once this parent is selected? e.g. to Tab 2? Just asking.. could you confirm that this is a must for you?

Comment: 1 minute please... I'll explain

Comment: Check another response, and its plunker... Hope now you'll get what you need ;)

Comment: Here is what I actually tried to do http://imgur.com/ltuLAo2. This is what my 'page2' layout should look like. Left bottom list is what I called 'tabId1/2/3'. Graph, filters and table are part of 'page2.tab' view. In fact table is nested inside filters, so table is corresponding to 'page2.tab.subroute' and should be visible all day long regardless of navigation inside 'page' state. Its the first time I make design using ui.router, so I might have made some mistakes. Thank you once again