# Ionic, Angularjs, Mysql http post

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am just found out an ionic framework and was trying to learn it, but i meet some obstacle that i cannot figure out, tried to search for google does not help me much.

I am trying to create a login form that will be checked to mysql database, but it does not work, i am not sure where is the problem.

Here is my code

**Login.html**

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-balanced">
   <h1 class="title">Test</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-view title="Sign-In">
  <ion-content class="padding has-header">
    <ion-list>
       <ion-item>
          <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item>
          <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
       </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <button nav-clear class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="LogIn()">Login</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
   // check username or password from database
   $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
   $request = json_decode($postdata);
   $user = $request->user;
   $password = $request->password;

   mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
   mysql_select_db("dbname");
   $results = mysql_query("SELECT name, city FROM tbl_user WHERE   name='".user."' AND city='".$password."' LIMIT 1") or die('{"error":"Login error! Code: 003"}');
   $match  = mysql_num_rows($results);
   if($match > 0 ){
      echo "1";
   }else{
      echo "0";
   }
?>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

    .state('app', {
       url: "/app",
       abstract: true,
       templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
       controller: 'AppCtrl'
     })

    .state('login', {
       url: "/login",
       templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
       controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {
  $scope.LogIn = function() {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/api/login.php",
        data: {
        user: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
      },
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      });
      /*Successful HTTP post request or not */
      request.success(function (data){
        if (data == '1'){
          $scope.responseMessage = "You are in";
        }
        else {
          $scope.responseMessage = "Username or Password is incorrect";
        }
      })
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/services.js"></script>-->
  </head>
  <body>
      <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
   </body>
```

It cannot popup the message.
Someone can point me where is the problem?

Thanks before

Comment: did you checked in the console?

Comment: I found out that the problem is CORS, have enabled the CORS but another problem occur is that even i typed a correct combination of user and password, its still said that is wrong username and password. How do i checked the query that used by the login api?

Comment: why the controller.js is unable to get the value of the input text from login.html? tried in console that it said 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use an object (for example `$scope.user`) in which to store username and password. So the code becomes as below:

**Login.html**

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item>
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Username">
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
      <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password">
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.LogIn = function() {
    var request = {
        method: "post",
        url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/api/login.php",
        data: {
        user: $scope.user.username,
        password: $scope.user.password
      },
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      };
      /*Successful HTTP post request or not */
      $http(request).then(function (response){
        if (response.data == '1'){
          $scope.responseMessage = "You are in";
        }
        else {
          $scope.responseMessage = "Username or Password is incorrect";
        }
      })
  }
});
```

Another suggestion is to use $http in the right form:

```
$http({
  ...
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

N.B.: if you want you can pass the user object directly as argument of LogIn() method.

Comment: tried your code, but did not solve the error, same error occured, tried to pass user object directly as LogIn(user) did not do any help.

Comment: if you add console.log($scope.user); inside $scope.LogIn() function you receive an empty object?

Comment: yes, i will receive undefined status in console log.

Comment: Please share also index.html. Another suggestion is to use $http in the right form: `$http({...}).then(function successCallback(response) { ...  }, function errorCallback(response) { ...  });` (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: added index.html, not sure how to use the GET method, never used it before. any help?

Comment: no, I thought about using `$http().then( successCb(), errorCb() );`, it doesn't matter which HTTP method, GET or POST.

Comment: another problem in your code is that in the success handler of $http promise the argument `response` is an object with `data` property (I edited my answer) which actually contains data from server.

Comment: last but not least: in your PHP code you missed a **$** char in the line `$results = mysql_query(...` for `$user` variable.

Comment: hi @beaver, it works by adding $scope.user as you suggested. just wanted to understand more, what the different between with and without $scope.user object?

Comment: It's related to how AngularJS scope inheritance works (that is in general how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works). Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play: so, use `$scope.model.variable` instead of `$scope.variable`. See more details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107012/scope-and-controller-instantiation-with-ui-router and in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes