# Ionic-Angularjs-Restful-webService project structure

Tags: mysql, angularjs, web-services, rest, ionic-framework

Can someone give me a sample project of Ionic-AngularJs-Spring(Controller Based)-Mysql which has the complete end to end flow from UI - Database?

And in addition to that can you please give me the POST, GET from UI to DB.

I have some trouble in understanding Connection between AngularJs to WebService while I POST, GET data from Ionic Screen and view the response.

Answer (score 1):

> for api call you can use this way..

```
$http({
    url: "http://example.appspot.com/rest/app",
    method: "POST",
    data: {"foo":"bar"}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ngMessages'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('signin', {
      url: '/sign-in',
      templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
      controller: 'SignInCtrl'
    })
    .state('forgotpassword', {
      url: '/forgot-password',
      templateUrl: 'templates/forgot-password.html'
    })
    .state('tabs', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: '/facts2',
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/facts2.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: '/about',
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/about.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: '/navstack',
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/nav-stack.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: '/contact',
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/contact.html'
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sign-in');

})

.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.user = {
    username: '',
    password : ''
  };
  $scope.signIn = function(form) {
    console.log(form);
    if(form.$valid) {
    console.log('Sign-In', $scope.user.username);
    $state.go('tabs.home');
    }
  };
  
})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Sign-in, Then Tabs Example</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="templates/form-errors.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">This field is required.</div>
      <div class="form-error" ng-message="minlength">This field is must be at least 5 characters.</div>
      <div class="form-error" ng-message="maxlength">This field is must be less than 50 characters</div>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/sign-in.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Sign-In">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <form name="signinForm" novalidate="" ng-submit="signIn(signinForm)">

            <div class="list">
              <label class="item item-input" 
                     ng-class="{ 'has-error' : signinForm.username.$invalid}">
                <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                <input type="text"
                       name="username"
                       ng-model="user.username" 
                       ng-minlength="5" 
                       ng-maxlength="10" 
                       required>
              </label>

              <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="signinForm.username.$error" ng-messages-include="templates/form-errors.html">
                <div class="form-error" ng-message="maxlength">This field is must be less than 10 characters</div>
              </div>

              <label class="item item-input" 
                     ng-class="{ 'has-error-lr' : signinForm.password.$invalid  && signinForm.$submitted, 'valid-lr' : signinForm.password.$valid  && signinForm.$submitted}">
                <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                <input type="password"
                       name="password"
                       ng-model="user.password" 
                       ng-minlength="5" 
                       ng-maxlength="25"
                       required>
              </label>
              <div class="form-errors" 
                   ng-show="signinForm.password.$error && signinForm.$submitted"
                   ng-messages="signinForm.password.$error"
                   ng-messages-include="templates/form-errors.html">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="padding">
              <button class="button button-block button-positive">
                Sign-In
              </button>
              <p class="text-center">
                <a href="#/forgot-password">Forgot password</a>
              </p>
            </div>

          </form>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/forgot-password.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Forgot Password">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>
            Yeah this is just a demo showing how views can be shown without tabs, then you can navigate
            to views within tabs. Additionally, only one set of tabs needs to be written for all of the different views that should go inside the tabs. (Compared to written the same tab links in the footer of every view that's in a tab.)
          </p>
          <p>
            There's no username/password, just click
            the Sign-In button back a the sign-in view.
          </p>
          <p>
            Return to <a href="#/sign-in">Sign-In</a>.
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view>
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

          <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
            <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>

          <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios7-information" href="#/tab/about">
            <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>

          <ion-tab title="Sign-Out" icon="ion-log-out" href="#/sign-in">
          </ion-tab>

        </ion-tabs>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>Example of Ionic tabs. Navigate to each tab, and
            navigate to child views of each tab and notice how
            each tab has its own navigation history.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    
    <script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
          <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
          <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
          <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
          <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
          <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="About">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
          <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
          <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
        <ion-content padding="true">
          <p><img src="https://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Hitarthi, Could you provide me some link for sample project Ionic - AngularJs - RestFul Web service - DB

Comment: welcome...@SrikanthPragallapati..
this is some of links that might helps you:
1)http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/posting-data-from-ionic-app-to-php-server/
2)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713234/ionic-angularjs-mysql-http-post