# Accessing Scope onExit of Angular-UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, exit, enter

I'am looking for the following possibility:

```
$stateProvider.state('user', angularAMD.route({
        url: '/user/:id',
        templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
        controllerUrl: 'views/user',
        controller: 'UserCtrl',
        onExit: function () {
            alert ("exit user");
           // call scope function saveCurrentStateData();

        }
    }));
```

**saveCurrentStateData()** stores some scope data (e.g. **$scope.my.data**) via a defined REST-Service at the backend.

**EDIT:** Can you give me a solution without `$scope.$on ('destroy',..` maybe with **resolve** property of ui-router ? Why can't I use `onExit`, why it is here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can listen to the `$destroy` `$scope` event of your controller

```
var UserCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        // Do your cleanup here or call a function that does
    });
};
```

And for a bit of reference of when does controller get instantiated and destroyed on ui-router, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107012/scope-and-controller-instantiation-with-ui-router)

**EDIT 1:** If you want to access your $state parameters you can listen to the `$stateChangeStart` or `$stateChangeSuccess` events and do something like this

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState,fromParams) {
            if(fromState.name == 'yourstate'){
                // Here is your param
                console.log(fromParams.stateid);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT 2:** The reason that you cannot use `onExit` is because by the time that method is called the state has been already changed. However this is fixed in the next major version (1.0) by adding an injectable service called `$transition$` which will provide access to the parameters of the state, you can read more about that [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1257)

Comment: Please consider that `$state.params.stateid` is not working within `$scope.$on('destroy',..` --> I need that there..

Comment: Then I believe you need to use the `$stateChangeSuccess` event, I do something similar in my applications but normally that state id represents something like a user, and that user lives within a service, meaning I know which user was on the page by accessing my service which does not get destroyed.  There is no individual state events, just catch all.

Comment: Updated answer with explanation of onExit @Vienna

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$destroy` event of your controller, which is part of the controller lifecycle.

```
// In controller
$scope.$on('$destroy', function iVeBeenDismissed() {
  // say goodbye to your controller here
  $scope.saveCurrentStateData();
})
```

Read more for [What is the lifecycle of an AngularJS Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094940/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-an-angularjs-controller)

Comment: Why can't I use onExit ?

Comment: Because you don't have access to your controller scope. You can of course access your `$stateParams` also from your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this event of ui-router

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', stateChangeStart(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
// enter your code here;
});
```

or use this event

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', stateChangeSuccess(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
// enter your code here;
});
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I need something like "stateBeforeExit"

Comment: @Vienna in this case you may use a (angular) service you should update while you are in the required state, and inject it to the onExit function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are still interesting on the reason since there is an answer accepted. But I got a [somehow related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579158/ui-router-transition-superseded-when-traversing-multi-views-state-tree) days ago and happened to see this question. I felt none of the previous answers got the exact point, so I'd to make mine. If my guess is correct, it is merely because the exit event did not happen at all (there is no full code in your question).

The exit of state happens if you navigate to ancestor states or sibling states, or sibling of an ancestor, but does not happen if you navigate to a descendant state. [The document](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) says:

> When the application is in a particular state—when a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well.

I made [a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0QPAGm8LSLd3v28CFlhr?p=preview) to illustrate; hope it can answer the question.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="demo">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script>
          let app = angular.module('demo', ['ui.router']);
        
          app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($up, $sp) {
            $sp.state(state1);
            $sp.state('state1.state2', state2);
            $sp.state('state1.state3',state3);
            $up.otherwise('/');
          }]);
          
          let state1 = {
            name: 'state1',
            url: '/',
            controller: function () {},
            template: `<p>I am state1</p>
            <div ui-view="state2view">
              <a ui-sref="state1.state2"> Jump to state1.state2</a>
            </div>
            <div ui-view="state3view">
              <a ui-sref="state1.state3"> Jump to state1.state3</a>
            </div>`,
            onExit: function(){alert('Goodbye state1')}
          };
          
          let state2 = {
            name: 'state1.state2',
            views: {
              state2view: {
                controller: function () {},
                template: 'I am state1.state2'
              }
            },
            onExit: function(){alert('Goodbye state1.state2')}
          };
          
          let state3 = {
            name: 'state1.state3',
            views: {
              state3view: {
                controller: function () {},
                template: 'I am state1.state3'
              }
            },
            onExit: function(){alert('Goodbye state1.state3')}
          };
    
        </script>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <ui-view></ui-view>
      </body>
    </html>
```