# Angular $watch doesn't work properly with state provider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to observe the inputs in each view in the stateProvider.
I prepared Plunker, which shows what the problem is.    [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cduXLa2KWPavWfvBhegE)

I use $watch like this:

```
  $scope.$watch('Group', function(newValues, oldValues) {
      console.log(newValues);
 }, true);
```

If I add data to input 1 or input 2 then $watch will also observe inputs 3 and 4. 
But if I first add data to input 3 or input 4 then $watch doesn't observe those inputs. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention the `controller` for your other states. So it won't work.

To utilise the same controller `$scope`, You need to create the `$scope.Group = {};` inside your `mainController`.

Your plunker works when you put value in `item1 and 2`, because the `$scope.Group` gets created and you utilise benefit of `prototypal inheritance.`

Your plunker didn't work when you put value in `item3 and 4`, because there is no Controller associated with your `state`, and there is no such `$scope.Group` exist on `mainController $scope`.

> Further : Try to put `{{$$childHead.Group}} - {{$$childTail.Group}}`
>   in your Plunker HTML and see `item 3 & 4` gets created as child
>   scope.

See this [working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/DkizixPvOd4K6e7kWKnS?p=preview)

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29115009/3455035)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `ng-controller='mainController'` in the templates as well.

You can put it in the input tag as follows:

`<input ng-controller="mainController" type="text"  ng-model="Group.item4" placeholder="Group.item4">`