# Angular UI router - does a nested view's controller automatically become a child of the parent view's controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, angular-ui-router, state

Here's my UI-Router configuration. I have a main products view and two nested states underneath that. I want each nested view to have its own controller, but I also want to be able to inherit some basic information from the parent controller (productsCtrl). My assumption would be that I could access productsCtrl from productShowCtrl, but it keeps coming back as undefined. Do productsCtrl and productShowCtrl not have a parent-child relationship by default?

```
var myProducts = angular.module('Products', [
  'ProductsShow'
])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('store.products', {
        url: '/products',
        views: {
          'subhead@': {
            templateUrl:'products/list/subhead.tmpl.html'
          },
          'content@': {
            templateUrl:'products/list/list.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'ProductsCtrl as productsCtrl'
          }
        }
    })
    .state('store.products.create', {
      url: '/create',
      views: {
        'subhead@': {
          templateUrl: 'products/create/subhead.tmpl.html'
        },
        'content@': {
          templateUrl: 'products/create/create.tmpl.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('store.products.show', {
      url: '/:productId',
      views: {
        'subhead@': {
          templateUrl: 'products/show/subhead.tmpl.html'
        },
        'content@': {
          templateUrl: 'products/create/create.tmpl.html',
          controller: 'ProductShowCtrl as productShowCtrl',
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

ProductsCtrl (for the main products view):

```
myProducts.controller('ProductsCtrl', function($stateParams) {
    var productsCtrl = this;
    productsCtrl.parentTest = "PARENT";
});
```

ProductsShowCtrl (for the child view):

```
angular.module('ProductsShow', [])
  .controller('ProductShowCtrl', function($stateParams) {
      var productShowCtrl = this;
      productShowCtrl.childTest = "CHILD";

      console.log('parent: ', productsCtrl.parentTest);
  });
```

I can't access `productsCtrl.parentTest` from `ProductShowCtrl`. How can I access it?

Comment: Check this Q & A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310

Comment: How would I get this working with controller as syntax though? It's more straightforward with $scope.

Comment: I created working example, provided more details and added some links to farther explanation how that all could work. Now you know even how to use `controllerAs` syntax... hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are related Q & A:

- [ui router - nested views with shared controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27768033/1679310)
- [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

I created [special working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zi0jwz6Bi7HCpOelhaIH?p=preview)

The example here with **`controllerAs`** could be like this:

The state defintion:

```
 .state("main", {
      controller:'mainController',
      controllerAs:'mainCtrl',
      url:"/main",
      templateUrl: "main_init.html"
  })  
  .state("main.1", {
      controller:'childController',
      parent: 'main',
      url:"/1",
      templateUrl: 'form_1.html'
  })  
  .state("main.2", {
      controller:'childController',
      parent: 'main',
      url: "/2",
      templateUrl: 'form_2.html'
  })
```

Main controller will define the **`Model`**:

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
  var Model = {Name : "xxx"}; // controller property Model
})
```

And in *form_1* or *form_2* we can access that model with **`controllerAs`** syntax:

```
<div>
  <h5>Child state FORM 2</h5>
  <pre>{{mainCtrl.Model}}</pre>

  Change the value in a child state FROM 2
  <input ng-model="mainCtrl.Model.Name" />
</div>
```

Where **`mainCtrl.Model`** represents the reference to parent controller *(inside of our and its $scope)*

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zi0jwz6Bi7HCpOelhaIH?p=preview)

Comment: I notice in the Plunkr that the name value doesn't change if I put something new in the form.

Comment: It seems that the input only properly binds to the parent controller if I use Model.Name instead of mainCtrl.Model.Name. Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using controller as syntax, because Model just hangs off $scope?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry, and made a wrong definition... Well, now, the PARENT controller has property `var Model`, and we can access that in child via scope inheritance $scope.mainCtrl.Model.... hope it does give the answer... sorry for quick but a bit broken example ;)

Answer (score 1):

The $scope doesn't work like that. They don't have a parent-child relationship by default like you asked. You can read more about it in the angular api docs.
The $rootScope has, but still it's bad practice in my opinion.

What you should do in angular when you want to access a variable in two different controllers like your trying you should create a service (factory) to do that.

Maybe you should have a products service in which you could declare variables and functions to access those variables in the conrollers.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that from the ui-Router [official](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) docs

> Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only
>
> Keep in mind that scope properties only inherit down the state chain
>   if the views of your states are nested. Inheritance of scope
>   properties has **nothing to do with the nesting of your states** and
>   everything to do with the nesting of your views (templates).
>
> It is entirely possible that you have nested states whose templates
>   populate ui-views at various non-nested locations within your site. In
>   this scenario you cannot expect to access the scope variables of
>   parent state views within the views of children states.

So you can not have the scope variables in above way. 
If you wants to share data across the states you can do in following ways :

1). Any time you need to share data across states you will need to **create a service/factory** that you can instantiate in your controllers associated with those states. The factory will consist of basic getters and setter for the different data you need to share. Just like when you build getters and setters in java to share across classes.

Demo : Working [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/xhzFMuK2tteFeNRggTuQ/preview) with this approach.

2). You can set a **global variable with $rootScope**. It will be accessible everywhere since its global, I strongly advise you don't do this but though I would point it out to you anyway.

3).When a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well.So you can **build your states considering the parent-child relationship** and share data across scopes in hierarchical manner.

Demo : Working [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Jbli2GECwcD3QQTjL8fd/preview) with mentioned approach.