# Angularjs read $scope in only root state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ionic` and `angularjs`.

My app.

```
.state('auth', {
  url: '/auth',
  abstract:true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/auth.html',
  controller: 'authCtrl'
})
.state('auth.reg', {
  url: '/reg',
  templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
  controller: 'regCtrl'
});
```

I have this in my `auth.html` *(root view)* :

```
{{authHeader}}
```

My `controller.js`

```
.controller('authCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  // here can get the scope
  // $scope.authHeader = "register";
})


.controller('regCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  // here CAN NOT get the scope
  $scope.authHeader = "register";
});
```

Only in **root controller** I can get the `$scope`. I want to add another controller called `login`, and change there to login. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $rootScope for this purpose

```
.controller('authCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
  // here can get the scope
  // $rootScope.authHeader = "register";
})
```

And in reg:

```
.controller('regCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
  // here CAN NOT get the scope
  $rootScope.authHeader = "register";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $rootScope for this purpose

```
.controller('authCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
  // here can get the scope
  // $rootScope.headerData.authHeader = "register";
})
```

And in reg:

```
.controller('regCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
  // here CAN NOT get the scope
  $rootScope.headerData = {authHeader : "register"};
});
```

In your model please use -

```
{{headerData.authHeader}}
```

It will always update when controller change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to introduce a Model (a reference object)

```
$scope.Model = { authHeader : "register" };
```

That will be inherited by each sub-state and could be changed

usage would be

```
// {{authHeader}}
{{Model.authHeader}}
```

See more details here:

#### [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32491555/1679310)