# Share $Scope data between States

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying access the parent state from a child. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('compareCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
 $scope.test=$scope.$parent.services;
```

app.coffee

```
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource'
                  , 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch'])
  .config ($stateProvider) ->
    $stateProvider.state('home',
      url: "/"
      templateUrl: "home.html"
    ).state('services',
      url: "/services"
      templateUrl: "services/list.html"
    ).state('services.detail',
      url: "/detail/"
      templateUrl: "detail.html"
    ).state('services.compare',
      url: "/compare/"
      templateUrl: "compare.html"
    )
```

Comment: Shared data should be in a service my friend. You never know at what level in scope hierarchy will the actual data reside. Or it maybe in a different hierarchy altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI-Router supports data (Model) sharing among state families. The detailed explanation could be found here

[How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

Where we can see, that we need to introduce a Model, a cluster, a reference object.

```
// controller of the parent state 'services'
.controller('ServicesCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.Model = { prop1 : value1, ...};
}])
```

Because now each child state will prototypically inherit that reference to $scope.Model... we can access it in any child state controller

```
.controller('ServiceChildCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.Model.prop1 = differentValue;
}])
```

Check it in action in [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cqx77pb4CDI2TXyESYGN?p=preview)