# Share the scope with angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-ui-router

How can I share the scope with angular ui router ? I tried this :

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('detailCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
 $scope.test=$scope.$parent.services;


angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource'
                  , 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch'])
  .config ($stateProvider) ->
    $stateProvider.state('home',
      url: "/"
      templateUrl: "home.html"
    ).state('services',
      url: "/services"
      templateUrl: "services.html"
    ).state('services.detail',
      url: "/detail/"
      templateUrl: "detail.html"
    )
```

in servicesCtrl :

```
$scope.services = getServices.query();
```

Comment: Here's another similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696612/how-do-i-share-scope-data-between-states-in-angularjs-ui-router

...should help.

Comment: Use a service to share data between different controllers in your application.