# Angular ui-router: child state not accessing parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm making use of `ui.router`'s nested views in my Angular app.
This is the relevant portion of my `.config`:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
})
.state('admin', {
    url: '/admin',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/admin/admin-dashboard.html',
    controller: 'AdminCtrl'
})
.state('admin.page-1', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/admin/page-1/page-1.view.html',
    controller: 'AdminCtrl'
})
```

What's happening is, although the `admin.page-1` view is being loaded correctly inside the `admin` view, it seems to not have access to `AdminCtrl`.

This is the controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('peaches')
        .controller('AdminCtrl', Controller);

    Controller.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function Controller($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.test = "Hello."
        console.log(vm.test);

        vm.organization  = {
            name: "Western Fund"
        };

        activate();

        function activate() {

        }
    }
})();
```

The `console.log(vm.test)` DOES work when I go to `admin.page-1`, but it does not seem to load inside my nested view, `page-1.view.html`, here:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1>{{vm.test}}</h1>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `vm` might be unkown. Try to add `controllerAs : 'vm'` in your route Provider for your page

Comment: you are using controllerAs in your HTML but I am not able to see any configuration for that in your router definition

Comment: I didn't configure controllerAs anywhere, I thought ui.router took care of that automatically when using var vm = this. That was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Apédémak and dhavalcengg said, I hadn't defined `controllerAs` in my routes, so `vm` was not defined. This fixed the problem:

```
.state('admin', {
    url: '/admin',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/admin/admin.html',
    controller: 'AdminCtrl as vm'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about sharing $scope between parent and child using ui-router. here is the post that explains it with example https://stackoverflow.com/a/27699798/284225