# How do I access a variable in parent state controller into child state in UI-router

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Issue Simulation:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZPgMxGwhha7S1cmTSNg8?p=info

Description: I want to share the data of parent state to child state. I am not creating a separate controller for child states. Also I am creating a nested views. So ideally children should share the parent scope. But it is not working.

```
this.successHandler = function(data){
   console.log("Inside Success Handler");
   mainCtrl.company = data;
};
```

I am initializing the company object in parent scope and binding it with the view of child state.

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="mainCtr.company.name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
```

I have checked one of the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27699798/1865844). But somehow it is not working in my case. Also I am trying to avoid usage of $scope and using "this" instead. Can someone help me accessing "mainCtrl.company" data inside all the three tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing it correctly, except having mispelt `mainCtrl` as `mainCtr` in your child views.

Comment: Oh Thanks alot. Thats working. A silly mistake from my side.

Comment: @MaheshKedari no problem, an extra pair of eyeballs helps when you've looked at your own code for too long!

Answer (score 0):

In short, angular's child `scope` inherits from its parent `scope`, which is available in view without the `$scope` prefix. Because you use `this` instead of `$scope` to manage your data and fields, you need to create a `communicate property`  (what `controllerAs` do here) . If there is no 'controllerAs', let's say we want a `parent` property, (add `$scope.parent = this;` in mainController L:29), and access with parent.company.name in the 3 child states with

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="parent.company.name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
```