# Angular Ui-Router | Accesing a scope variable in a view from controller, but not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I have this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFyQvRHVC1f07E9I8YF4?p=preview). I define two controllers: **`mainController`** and **`itemsController`**. I want to access to the scope variable **`items`** from a view, but I can't.

To reproduce, you need to click first in the button **`Populate Items`**, (the array item is populated from a **`service`**) and you see in the **`console`** the values. Then click in the button **`Say Hello !`** and then you will see that items is empty; but, the variable **`tab`** is being accessed.

I think that I'm not applying in the correct way the definitions of the controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [updated and working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l2DrJ78hilB5nNQrw9u0?p=preview)

What we need, is the data sharing:

#### [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

so instead of this

```
  app.controller("itemsController", 
   function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams, Data) {
    $scope.items = []; // local reference, not shared

    $scope.getFromJson = function() {
      Data.get().then(function handleResolve(resp) {
        $scope.items = resp;
        console.log($scope.items);
      });
    };
  })
```

we will fill the shared reference **`$scope.Model.items = resp;`**

```
  app.controller("itemsController", 
   function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $stateParams, Data) {

    $scope.getFromJson = function() {
      Data.get().then(function handleResolve(resp) {
        $scope.Model.items = resp;
        console.log($scope.Model.items);
      });
    };
  })
```

which will be hooked on the super root home. So, instead of this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("home", {
    abtract: true,
    url: "/home",
    resolve: {
      $title: function() {
        return 'Tab1';
      }
    },
    views: {
      "viewA": {
        templateUrl: "home.html"
      }
    }
  });
```

we will have that:

```
  .state("home", {
    abtract: true,
    url: "/home",
    resolve: {
      $title: function() {
        return 'Tab1';
      }
    },
    views: {
      "viewA": {
        templateUrl: "home.html",
        // HERE we do the magic
        // this is a super parent view
        // at which $scope we will have shared reference Model
        controller: function($scope){
          $scope.Model = {}
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l2DrJ78hilB5nNQrw9u0?p=preview)

Comment: This is amazing and very interesting ! Thanks again for your help !