# Pass JSON data from AJAX call to another view in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a simple search form that passes to a controller that fires an AJAX request to Flickr.  Upon receiving the returned data I want to change to another view for display of the results.  Everything works fine except that I am unable to pass the JSON data between the two views.  I've tried various permutations of `state.go('results', {...}` and adding `params` to the `stateProvider` but this doesn't appear to work for me - as this doesn't appear to be a particularly unusual thing to want to achieve I'm obviously missing something rather daft.  Presumably.

**Main App.js**

```
var photoApp = angular.module('photoApp', ['infinite-scroll', 'ui.router']);

photoApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/Client/Views/partial-search.html'
    })
    .state('results', {

        templateUrl: '/Client/Views/partial-results.html',      
        params: { 'photos': ''}
    });

});
```

**Controller**

```
//snip
$scope.processForm = function($stateParams){

        //snip

        $http({
            method: 'JSONP',
            url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=' + key + '&text=' + $scope.formData.search + '&extras=owner_name,tags,description',
            params: {
                'format': 'json',
                'jsoncallback': 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
        }).success(function (data) {

            $scope.photo = data.photos;
            $state.go('results', { 'photos': $scope.photo });
        });
    };

    $scope.loadMore = function () {

       // populate an 'infinite scroll in the results page
        }
    };
};
app.controller("FlickrController", FlickrController);
```

**partial-results.html** - builds a four-column grid of images

```
<div ng-controller="FlickrController">
  <div class="row">
    <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
        <div ng-repeat='image in images'>        
                ...
```

In case the flow isn't clear:  View 1(searchform) -> processForm()(controller) -> view2 (partial-results.html) -> loadMore() (controller).  It's getting the `$scope.photos` to be available in the partial-results view that is the issue.

Comment: One way is some service as a storage, I do prefer to to use scope sharing ... see more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

Comment: How do you access `$stateParams.photos`?
What does your `$scope.images` object look like?
The relevant code is missing here.

Comment: `$scope.images` just helps populate a photo wall - this works fine and isn't related to the above problem - it's part of the `infinite scroll / ng-repeat`.  
Accessing `$stateParams.photos`? Wrongly as it appears from @RadimKöhler 's link - two instances of the FlickrController.

Comment: Hmm... making `results` a child of `home` as per the linked post above breaks `state.go()` so the results page never loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing data between controllers should generally be done through *services*, so should the API calls. It's not mandatory but a best practice, you get a better architecture and you also get less headaches. It's like this:

*Controller1* <----> **ServiceData** <----> *Controller2*

The `$state` method should be used for navigation purposes and sending simple parameters between *views* or *states*.

**Your specific case, TL'DR**:
 *(just my 2 cents, there other alternatives)*

- You should have a *FlickerService* that will:

  1. hold the list of results (ie: `FlickerService.someObject={someProperty:"anything", resultsList:[]};`)  and
  2. will provide a method for you to update that list,with a parameter telling you want more results (for infinite scroll) besides the search parameters. Let's call it `grabFlickerData(searchQueryJson, loadMoreResults)`, *Note: the `key` should be kept in a config file and you will use it in the service, but it's not the priority now* .
  3. that method will just return the http promise (`return $http.get(.../*your old code here*/...)`.
  4. On the success callback (`.success(function (data) {..}`) you will get the data from the API and put it in in your object: `FlickerService.someObject.resultsList = data`. You can also iterate through the items, process each item and do a `FlickerService.someObject.resultsList.push(item)` one by one if you need more control over the result items. *Note: if you need to repeatedly add data to the list you may want to **append** the `data` to the array instead of replacing it.*
- In your `partial-search` controller you call the service method when you need the data (in `processForm` or `loadMore` methods, or both, or wherever)
- again, in the `partial-search` controller, you will get the *$http promise* from the service together with the data and the 2 callbacks: for *success* and *error*, just like you did in the service. You don't need to touch the data here but, most important, on the *success* callback you redirect to the other state: `$state.go('results')`. Note that you don't need to send any other data. You may want to pass a result if you like, ie:*'All Good, we have data'* if you feel the urge to communicate between the 2 controllers.
- in the `partial-results` controller you will define a scope variable bound to the list in the service, like `$scope.greatResults = FlickerService.someObject.resultsList` and use it:
- in the `partial-results` view: `<div ng-repeat="result in greatResults">...</div>` or use the list how you want
- for infinite scroll you just need to call the service method telling it to get you more results (with the parameter described above).

Hope this helps a little; if you have questions add a comment. I may come back later to edit the answer with more code samples if needed.

Comment: Thank-you - that all makes far more sense than what I was attempting.  I'll work through it now and return.

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know how it goes and I'll get back with details if needed