# angularjs - array updated but view did not update when using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use `ui-router` to route to particular sub page as needed:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ui.router']);
    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('usergroups', {
  url: "/usergroups",
  templateUrl: "pages/usergroups.html",
  controller : 'UsergroupsCtrl'
  })
  .state('usergroups.create', {
  url: "/create",
  templateUrl: "pages/usergroups.new.html",
  controller : 'UsergroupsCtrl'
  })

...
```

This is my `usergroups.html`:

```
  <body>
    <h3>User Groups</h3><br/>

    <button class="fon-btn" type="button" ng-hide = "toAdd" ng-click="toAdd = true"  ui-sref="usergroups.create">Create New Group</button>  
    <div ui-view></div>
      <ul>
        <li class="bitcard padding10" ng-repeat="group in usergroups">
            <span class="padding10"><strong>{{group.name}}</strong></span>
        </li>
        </ul>
  </body>
```

and `usergroups.new.html`:

```
<body>
<form ng-submit="add()">
      <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Add Usergroup"><br/><br/>
      </form>
</body>
```

When I click on `Add Usergroup`, it will called `add()` from `UsergroupsCtrl`:

```
$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.usergroups.push({name:$scope.name});
    console.log($scope.usergroups);
    }
```

The console show that `$scope.usergroups` is already updated. but somehow in `usergroups.html`: `ng-repeat="group in usergroups"` did not update the view. I add `$scope.$apply()` and `$scope.$digest()` but got an error:

> $apply already in progress

But everything works fine if I did not use `ui-router`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Don't think that controller `UsergroupsCtrl` is shared between parent and child route. The controller refreshes on each route change.

Comment: why don't you try creating a service so you can share data among different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I think same `$scope` cannot be used in two different controllers. you can change it to $rootScope. like `$rootScope.usergroups.push()`. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696612/how-do-i-share-scope-data-between-states-in-angularjs-ui-router) may help you. You can use `$stateParam` also.

Comment: I got an error: `Error: Can't find variable: $stateParam`

Comment: you have to inject $stateParams and than you can use it. did you go through ui-router doc ? here it is https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/