# Unable to change the name of login button using ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am setting a boolean value to true after user logs in and I want to update the login button status to logout. I tried using ng-show but apparently its not working.

States:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Home");
    var header = {
        templateUrl: 'commonViews/Header.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }

    };
    var footer = {
        templateUrl: 'commonViews/Footer.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }
    };
    // ui router states
$stateProvider
    .state('Home', {
        url: "/Home",
        views: {
            header: header,
            content: {
                templateUrl: 'views/HomePage.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            },
            footer: footer
        }
    })
    .state('LoggedIn', {
        url: "/LoggedIn",
        views: {
            'header': header,
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/LoggedIn.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            },
            'footer': footer
        }
    });
});
```

UserService:

```
myApp.factory('UserService', function ($http, $localStorage, AuthenticationService) {
    return {
        logIn: function (email, password) {
            return $http.post('rs/loginResource/login', {email: email, password: password})
                    .then(function (data) {
                        AuthenticationService.isLogged = true;
                        alert("Authentication loggedIn inside login controller: " + AuthenticationService.isLogged);
                        return data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
        },
        logOut: function () {
            if (AuthenticationService.isLogged) {
                AuthenticationService.isLogged = false;
                delete $localStorage.token;
            }
        }
    };
});

myApp.factory('AuthenticationService', function () {
    var auth = {
        isLogged: false
    };
    return auth;
});
```

Login controller:

```
myApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'jwtHelper', '$localStorage', '$sessionStorage', '$state', '$window', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService', function ($scope, $http, jwtHelper, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $state, $window, UserService, AuthenticationService)
    {
        $scope.token = "";
        $scope.$storage = $localStorage;
        $scope.loginForm = function (email, password) {

            if (email !== undefined && password !== undefined) {
                UserService.logIn(email, password).then(function (response) {
                    $localStorage.token = response.data.token;
                    if ($localStorage.token) {
                        $state.go('LoggedIn');
                        alert("scope loggedIn inside login controller: " + AuthenticationService.isLogged);
                    }
                }).catch(function (status, data) {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }

            $scope.logout = function logout() {
                UserService.logOut().success(function () {
                    $state.go('/');
                }).error(function (status, data) {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(data);
                });
            };
        };
    }]);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view="header"></div>
        <div ui-view="content"></div>
        <div ui-view="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Header html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-show="isLoggedIn" ng-click="logout()"><b>Logout</b></a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-show="!isLoggedIn"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <!---------------------------------Login Controller Here------------------------------------->
                        <li>
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <form class="form" role="form" method="post" ng-controller="loginController" ng-submit="loginForm(email, password)" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                            <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

After user is logged in, it changes the status to logout for split second and then back to login status again. I am not sure what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Add `AuthenticationService` to the scope of your controller,

```
$scope.AuthenticationService = AuthenticationService;
```

and remove `$scope` from your view/template

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="loginController">
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-show="AuthenticationService.isLogged" ng-click="logout()"><b>Logout</b></a>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-show="!AuthenticationService.isLogged"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Did not work. How will adding AuthenticationService to scope will solve my issue. I guess using `$scope.AuthenticationService.isLogged` is also same

Comment: you have 2 problems.  one is that you can't use `$scope` from within the template (e.g. you don't say `ng-click="$scope.logout()"`...you say `ng-click="logout()"`).  the problem that you'll have after you fix the first problem is that `AuthenticationService` is not yet defined on `$scope` and won't be accessible from the view until you add it scope.

Comment: I set the `AuthenticationService` to scope like you said but its not working. Still shows login button instead of logout

Comment: ah. i left off the parens on the `isLogged` functions in the view.  see my updated answer (I just changed `ng-show="AuthenticationService.isLogged"` to `ng-show="AuthenticationService.isLogged()"`).  should work now.

Comment: `isLogged` is not a function in my `userService` but let me try and see

Comment: Why do you think its not working. The code looks right but from past few days I am trying to solve this issue

Comment: I am able to route to new page but only problem is unable to change the button name

Comment: sorry.  didn't look close enough.  you are right, i removed the parens.

Comment: is your `alert` firing? (the one in `UserService.logIn`)

Comment: Yes both the alerts are firing and showing the boolean value as true

Comment: You're not updating `AuthenticationService.isLogged` after login and logout. See my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

Put an `isLoggedIn()` function in your header controller:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Home");
    var header = {
        templateUrl: 'commonViews/Header.html',
        controller: function ($scope, AuthenticationService) {
            $scope.isLoggedIn = function() {
                 return AuthenticationService.isLogged;
            });
        }

    };
    var footer = {
        templateUrl: 'commonViews/Footer.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }
    };
    // ui router states
```

And in your header HTML use that function:

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
    ng-show="isLoggedIn()" ng-click="logout()"><b>Logout</b>
 </a>
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
    ng-show="!isLoggedIn()">
    <b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
```

**UPDATE**

Your login controller's scope is a child of the header controller's scope. Your `ng-show` directives are not in your login controller's scope. By putting functions that query the `AuthenticationService.isLogged` state in the correct scope, the `ng-show` directives should work properly.

Comment: I deleted this answer because @Arkantos seems to be helping you. But since you insist here it is. I think it will fix your show/hide problem but the login form will still be there after login.

Comment: Its working but one problem - that is when I refresh the page, the button changes back to login

Comment: This is the reason I was reluctant to answer your question. Your code has a lot of problems. Your login controller puts something in local storage but your `AuthenticationService` doesn't check local storage. You use scope variables to change your template instead of login state to change your template. It looks like you took two examples and just mixed them in a strange way. Your code is very fragile. Change one thing and something else will break.

Comment: hmmm ok. The `AuthenticationService` is not checking for local storage(contains JWT token) because it is already valid or else it will return false. I am very confused and I am a beginner in angular. I thought I should manually use `state.go` to change routes. How would stateProvider takes care of changing the template using states?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code

1. `AuthenticationService.isLogged`
   is not updated after successful login with UserService
2. You don't need to have `$scope` in your templates as any Angular expression that you pass in your HTML template will be resolved against the current scope.

I would suggest not to expose your services onto your view layer. Just add a property `isLoggedIn` on your scope which will determine whether to show Login or Logout buttons.

```
myApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'jwtHelper', '$localStorage', '$sessionStorage', '$state', '$window', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService', function ($scope, $http, jwtHelper, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $state, $window, UserService, AuthenticationService)
    {
        $scope.token = "";
        $scope.$storage = $localStorage;
        // new property to hold login status
        $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
        $scope.loginForm = function (email, password) {

            if (email !== undefined && password !== undefined) {
                UserService.logIn(email, password).then(function (response) {
                    $localStorage.token = response.data.token;
                    if ($localStorage.token) {
                        // cache the login status for use in other controllers
                        AuthenticationService.isLogged = true;

                        // update the scope for use in templates
                        $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
                        $state.go('LoggedIn');
                    }
                }).catch(function (status, data) {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }

            $scope.logout = function logout() {
                UserService.logOut().success(function () {
                   // cache the login status for use in other controllers
                    AuthenticationService.isLogged = false;

                   // update scope for use in templates
                    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;

                    $state.go('/');
                }).error(function (status, data) {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(data);
                });
            };
        };
    }]);
```

With this, in your templates, you can just check for `isLoggedIn` like below

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="loginController">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown" 
                    ng-show="isLoggedIn" 
                    ng-click="logout()">
          <b>Logout</b></a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" 
                    ng-show="!isLoggedIn">
          <b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are right. Exposing service in view layer is not a good practice. Let me give it a try

Comment: I guess the problem is with the states. The header.html is a separate file where login/logout buttons are there. I am using ui-router to inject header.html file and may this is the problem?

Comment: I think the issue is that you're updating `header`, `footer` and `content` when you go to `LoggedIn` state. So  your HTMLs are loaded again and your controllers are initialized again because of which `isLoggedIn` property on scope is reset

Comment: exactly that's what I was guessing that some thing is wrong with states. How do I not reload the header and footer? and have the scope values?

Comment: Ideally your login form should be in content view instead of header view and update only content view in your `LoggedIn` state. I would recommend you do that but there's a workaround to repopulate the scope using cached value from Authentication service, updated my answer for this

Comment: You can remove `header` and `footer` properties in `LoggedIn` state configuration

Comment: I can keep my form in content but my content view keeps changing based on routes

Comment: Yes that's the idea here. Do you always want to show your login form even after login ?

Comment: No I mean if the login form which has the `login` and `logout` buttons is kept inside content view and lets say I navigate to different content view which doesn't contain the logout button

Comment: In that case, keep your username, pwd fields and login button in your content view and keep the logout button in header view but hide/show this button based on loggedIn status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100222/discussion-between-arkantos-and-satyadev).

Comment: Not on system right now. Will ping you soon. Thank you

Comment: Hi are you available for chat?