# multistep form and sharing data with angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a multistep form and am having trouble sharing data between views/states.  I'm not sure that the way I'm even going about this is accurate as I am new to angular-ui-router.  Here are my routes:

```
.state('tab.newEventCategory', {
  url: '/activities/new-event-category',
  views: {
    'tab-patient': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/new-event-category.html',
      controller: 'ActivityDashboardCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('tab.newEventSubCategory', {
  url: '/activities/new-event-sub-category',
  views: {
    'tab-patient': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/new-event-sub-category.html'
    }
  }
})
```

I am trying to use the routes above so that once someone chooses a category, they then go to a page where they choose a subcategory.  Here is the new-event-category page:

```
<div ng-repeat="event_category in event_categories" class="padding">
    <a class="button button-block button-positive button-large" ng-click="moveToEventSubCategory(event_category)">
      {{event_category}}
    </a>
</div>
```

and here is the controller for the page:

```
.controller('ActivityDashboardCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, EventCategory, $state) {
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.event_categories = EventCategory.query();

  $scope.moveToEventSubCategory = function(event_category){
    $scope.formData.category = event_category;
    $state.go('tab.newEventSubCategory');
  }
})
```

My issue is that now I want the newEventSubCategory state to have access to the same formData object so it can add subcategories.  There will be more pages to this multistep form after this and I want them to all have access to the same formData variable.  How do I do this?

Comment: Create a service to get/set the form data

Comment: how would i do that?  i am very new to angular

Comment: Are you going to use one controller for all the steps or a single?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about.  I think it would be a better idea to use one.

Comment: Ok, if you want to use one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696612/how-do-i-share-scope-data-between-states-in-angularjs-ui-router else sharing data between controllers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers which would be related to my first comment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to communicate between controllers/states you best option it what @ronnie mentioned; creating a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) or factory.

Have a look at this if you want to work out what services are and how to user them: [AngularJS Step-by-Step: Services](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/angularjs-step-by-step-services)