# Filling common views in abstract state in UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Would this result in presenting the page with header, footer and content block filled with `content.list` view?

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/contacts',
        views: {
          header: { templateUrl: 'admin/header.html'},
          content: {
            templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.contacts = [{ id:0, name: "Alice" }, { id:1, name: "Bob" }];
            }
          },
          footer: { templateUrl: 'admin/footer.html'}
        }           
    })
    .state('contacts.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html'
    })
```

.

```
 <!-- index.html -->
 ...
 <div ui-view="header"></div>
 <div ui-view="content"></div>
 <div ui-view="footer"></div>   
 ...
```

.

```
<!-- contacts.html -->
<h1>Contacts Page</h1>
<div ui-view></div>
```

.

```
<!-- contacts.list.html -->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in contacts">
        <a ng-href="#/contacts/{{person.id}}">{{person.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't know... would it? try to code and see for yourself! also you have plenty of websites you can code without actually having to setup a workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jnusV4BpSSCPjU11QvjD?p=info).

The parent view's `$scope` *(the view, defined in state 'contacts' views as a 'content')* and its scope, will be a source for prototypical inheritance.

And that means, that its properties will be available in the child state 'contacts.list', because it is injected into that 'content' view

There is in detail more about it:

#### [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

To prove, it, we can extend the code snippet above with a list controller and inject some more contacts

```
    ...
    .state('contacts.list', {
      url: '/list',
      templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html',
      controller: 'listCtrl', // new controller
    })

  }
])
// we get already initiated contacts... coming from parent view
.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.contacts
      .push({ id: 2, name: "from a child" });

}])
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jnusV4BpSSCPjU11QvjD?p=info)

Comment: and if I use controllerAs syntax -  will this work? as I don't know if the prototype chain is created for controller objects of the view hierarchy.

Comment: ... YES ... it will work again and again.. because the way how we define controllers is not related to built in $scope inheritance. So, yes... all your expectations are ok ;)