# How to display the output of function in a controller to nested view in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-controller, nested-views

I have a parent view `index.html`

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script src = "assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "../lib/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src = "app.js"></script>
    <script src = "controllers/profile/ProfileController.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
     <div class="links">
       <div class='profile'><a ui-sref="profile">Profile</a></div>
       <div class='dashboard'><a ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
     </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

In `app.js`

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

   app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('profile', {
            url: "modules/profile/templates",
            templateUrl: "modules/profile/templates/profile.html",
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        }).state('dashboard', {
            url: "modules/dashboard/templates",
            templateUrl: "modules/dashboard/templates/index.html"
        }).state('profile.viewprofile', {
            url: "modules/profile/templates",
            templateUrl: "modules/profile/templates/viewprofile.html",
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        }).state('profile.createprofile', {
            url: "modules/profile/templates",
            templateUrl: "modules/profile/templates/createprofile.html",
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        });
    }
]);
```

This is my `profile.html`

```
 <div >
   <div class="links">
    <h3 class="heading">Profile</h3>
       <div class='viewprofile'><a ui-sref="profile.viewprofile">View Profile</a></div>
       <div class='createprofile'><a ui-sref="profile.createprofile">Create Profile</a></div>
       <div class='editprofile'><a ui-sref="profile.editprofile">Edit Profile</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content>
       <div ui-view="profile.viewprofile@"></div>
       <div ui-view="profile.createprofile@"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

in my `ProfileController`

```
app.controller('ProfileController',function($scope, $http){
        $scope.allProfiles = function(){
       $http.get('objects/getallprofiles.php').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    });
}
```

In console the data displayed is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [fname] => sdds
        [1] => sdds
        [lname] => sddssd
        [2] => sddssd
        [mobile] => 333
        [3] => 333
    )
)
```

When I click on `viewprofile` in `profile.html` page the `viewprofile.html` is getting rendered. But, I want to get the values of the function `allProfiles()` to the child view `viewprofile` and bind them to html tags

How can I get the `allProfiles()` function output which is in controller to the child view `viewprofile.html`

Comment: Here should be the answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310

Answer (score 1):

You can bind data inside allProfile() function to some rootScope variable. Like this:

```
$scope.allProfiles = function(){
       $http.get('objects/getallprofiles.php').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $rootScope.profiles=data;
    console.log(data);
    });
```

And then you can access this variable in any controller you want using $rootScope.

*Don't forget to inject $rootscope in cotroller.*

Another way of doing this is to store data in service and inject the service in a controller you want to access data.

Comment: it's not working. I am not even getting any alert if I put inside allProfiles() function

Comment: I am very new to angularjs. Will you please show how to store data in service and inject the service in a controller