# UI-router: deal with nested controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I have following config:

```
.state("addUser", {
        url: "/addUser",
        templateUrl: "users/add-user.html",
        controller: "AddUserParent",
        controllerAs: "$ctrl",
        abstract: true
    })
        .state("addUser.General", {
            url: "/General",
            templateUrl: "users/add-user-general.html",
            controller: "AddUser",
            controllerAs: "$ctrl",
        })
        .state("addUser.Cost", {
            url: "/Cost",
            templateUrl: "users/add-user-cost.html",
            controller: "AddUser",
            controllerAs: "$ctrl",
        })
        .state("addUser.Notes", {
            url: "/Notes",
            templateUrl: "users/add-user-notes.html",
            controller: "AddUser",
            controllerAs: "$ctrl",
        })
```

And following parent controller:

```
angular
    .module("users")
    .controller("AddUserParent", AddUserParent);

AddUserParent.$inject = ["usersSrv", "stateRouter"];
function AddUserParent(usersSrv, stateRouter) {
    let $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.navigate = stateRouter.navigate;
    $ctrl.user = {};

    $ctrl.addUser = function() {
        usersSrv.addUser($ctrl.user);
        console.log($ctrl.user);
        $ctrl.navigate('home');
    }
}
```

Child controller `AddUser` is just empty. When I fill in:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.user.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.user.location">
```

in `addUser.General` state and switch to `addUser.Cost` I lose all `$ctrl.user` data. Why does it happen so? How to fix this?

Comment: Here you can find the deep explanation of how to share data among states.. scopes http://stackoverflow.com/a/27699798/1679310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because when you navigate to another state even if the controller is the same, the controller gets reloaded which results in data loss. 
so you have multiple options to achieve that.

- you may use services,
- events
- shared master controller
- or passing parameter to the controller

Please check out [nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) section of [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) it will give you some insight to achieve passing parameters to controllers.

or you can configure the states like this so that all the states use the same master controller.

```
  .state("addUser.General", {
        url: "/General",
        templateUrl: "users/add-user-general.html"
    })
    .state("addUser.Cost", {
        url: "/Cost",
        templateUrl: "users/add-user-cost.html"
    })
    .state("addUser.Notes", {
        url: "/Notes",
        templateUrl: "users/add-user-notes.html"
    })
```

because you didn't specify controller on state definition, all the child states use the same master controller `AddUserParent`