# UI-Router state controller doesnt update scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI-router to control the states of a single page application. I have a big chain of states that I narrowed to these:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: "/",
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.main', {
      url: "/main",
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.main.users', {
      url: "/users",
      abstract: true,
      controller: 'UsersController',
      controllerAs: 'uc'
    })
    .state('app.main.users.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "list.html",
    });
```

Imagine that this app.main.users is an abstract state for a CRUD which will use the same controller for all the operations.

The problem is that the "list.html" file from the child controller cannot see the values from the controller.

<del>I have put up a plunkr sample to the issue: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/FO1WyMDE0A72cMetiFDL?p=preview)</del>

Here is the full code:

```
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: "/",
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.main', {
      url: "/main",
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.main.users', {
      url: "/users",
      abstract: true,
      controller: 'UsersController',
      controllerAs: 'uc'
    })
    .state('app.main.users.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "list.html",
    });
})

myapp.controller('UsersController', usersController);
  function usersController() {
    console.log("UsersController instantiated");
    var vm = this;
    vm.user = 'username';
  }
```

If you have any idea, please let me know. I can't find a solution to this.
Thanks!

Comment: Ive just saw the problem with the plunkr. Sorry for that, I ve had to change some code to make this sample so I might have forgot something. Ill take a look on it right now. Thanks.
I understood your point of just one state active at a time, but the fact that the top state is an abstract state, doesnt make the childs inherits its controller definitions?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696612/how-do-i-share-scope-data-between-states-in-angularjs-ui-router/27699798#27699798

Comment: Thanks! Ive saw this topic before, the problem is that I am not using $scope. I am using controllerAs syntax. When I navigate to the view, the HTML renders, the controllers functions are called and the vm.variables are changed, but this doesn't reflect on the rendered page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

I was missing some things in the concept of the states. First of all I needed an  on my app.main state so it could render the app.main.users state. Also my controllers declaration was wrong.

This [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/k5ICrfKs4ixnlTI0S8vQ/) is working with the desired scenario.

Thanks for the help.